# Вызов функции модуля sys

Tags: node.js

Вызывал функцию log модуля sys, написало

> "The "sys" module is now called "util". It should have a similar interface."

Я так понял, что теперь модуль sys переименован в util?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cм. [changelog](http://nodejs.org/changelog.html) от 2010.10.23 Version 0.3.0